# voce - Simple Java code not working

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I recently installed Voce and am using it in my Java application. In Eclipse, I added the JAR files in voce-0.9.1/voce-0.9.1/lib to the libraries in my Java Build Path. From the documentation, I figured that this code should work:

```
import voce.SpeechSynthesizer;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // System.out.println("Speaking");
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer("speaker");
        speaker.synthesize("hello");
        // System.out.println("Spoken");
        speaker.destroy();
    }
}
```

When I uncomment the output statements, the program outputs "Speaking", then almost immediately outputs "Spoken" without having made a sound. My volume is turned up. Does synthesize() speak the string or have I forgotten some initialization? And can you give me some code that *should* work?

**Answer**

Here is the code that worked (I used the static methods in SpeechInterface instead of a SpeechSynthesizer object):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        voce.SpeechInterface.init("../../../lib", true, false, "", "");
        System.out.println("Speaking");
        voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("hello");
        System.out.println("Spoken");
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch(Exception ex) {}
        voce.SpeechInterface.destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: `speaker.synthesize` probably run in a another thread .so you can see Spoken immediately

Comment: After it said "Spoken", Eclipse said that the application had terminated, but I didn't hear any "hello".

Comment: what is the library you are using ?

Comment: Voce: http://voce.sourceforge.net/

Comment: not sure.but according to the document , you can try

 `voce.SpeechInterface.init("../../../lib", true, false, "", "");
        voce.SpeechInterface.synthesize("hello");`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Make your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Although I do not understand why you specified the vocePath as "../../../lib".

Comment: i post this code from the example folder.the lib file is the path where the .jar/library  files are lying .since example exist in src folder they have used ../ to navigate to parent directory .i haven't use that library you may need to read more about this library.